# VSCode - Formatting - Opening tag (php) as left-most ruler for code until closing tag?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, indentation

When adding some php in the middle of html, the rest of the code gets auto-indented back to the far left of the page.

Googled this and couldn't find any information.

```
        <div id="assignment_data_page">
            <?php if (isset($args[1]) && is_numeric($args[1])) {
    print views_embed_view('assignment_set_fields', 'block', $args[1]);
}?>
```

would ideally look like

```
        <div id="assignment_data_page">
            <?php if (isset($args[1]) && is_numeric($args[1])) {
                print views_embed_view('assignment_set_fields', 'block', $args[1]);
            }?>
```

I'm using phpfmt for this formatting.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't have a html/php formatter extension. Try install one from the marketplace like PHP Intelephense below.
Then, to format the whole document, you can use these shortcuts:

- on MacOS: ⇧⌥F
- on Windows: Shift+Alt+F
- on Linux: Ctrl+Shift+I

I tested with your piece of code and managed to get proper formatting.

[image: PHP Intelephense]

Comment: I was using PHP Intellisense - Crane, an HTML formatter and phpfmt. Disabling those and using the one you provided gives the expected result. Thanks!